# Better method to load cookies for bootstrap elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I'm working on the option for hiding the panel's bodies and keep them hidden by reloading the page. It's a bootstrap driven code and the operation `$("#requests").collapse()` produces an animation that I don't like to see cause having 100 of panels collapsing each time by reloading the page can be annoying. So is there some better method to do this?

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    if(getCookie(cname) == 1) {
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + 0 + "; " + expires;
    } else {
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + 1 + "; " + expires;
    }
}

window.onload = function applyCookies() {
    if(getCookie("hidden") == 1) {  
        $("#requests").collapse();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I try not to override any bootstrap element or to change it. That is why I prefer to solve this problem by applying some bootstrap native attributes or functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(getCookie("hidden") == 1) {  
        $("#requests").hide();
    }
```

Comment: After applying `$("#requests").hide()` you can't hide or show the panel's bodies anymore. Also you still see how the bodies are hiding during the opening the page.

Comment: To show: `$("#requests").show()` . You see elements while loading the page because JQuery hasn't fully loaded and performed the HIDE function. So use this css: `#requests { display: none }`

Answer (score 0):

Add `#request{
    display:none;
}`

Now, you just change your function to this

```
window.onload = function applyCookies() {
    if(getCookie("hidden") == 0) {
         $("#requests").css("display","block");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I did after reading the first answer. But it's just the negation of the original code. Now I see plenty of panels opening each time I reload the page.

Comment: Maybe your cookies aren't being deleted properly. That would be the only way I could explain this to me

Comment: I think it's because of the same reason explained by @TheMatrixISReal.